# What is the difference between user name, display name and log-in name?

Tags: users

1. What is the difference between *user* name, *display* name and *log-in* name?
2. What are the consequences of modifying each of them if a substantial difference holds?
3. How do I modify these?

I understand that `usermod` is relevant here, but interpreting its options is not immediate without having that terminology clear. And there might be other commands that serve the same or similar purposes.

Pass. Thanks for clarifying this.

Comment: You'll probably want to show the context you're seeing each of those names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Which is which

**User name** is an ambiguous term that could refer

- to a formal **user ID** string known to some system, or
- to a **display name** like `John Smith`.

For that reason, we have more specific terms like **login name**, which informs us that this is the character string that is used for logging in, like `jsmith`, and not `John Smith`.

**User ID** also serves this purpose, but it is ambiguous against a **numeric user ID**. That has to be clear from context. For instance in Unix, users don't usually deal with numeric user IDs; if a prompt asks for a "user ID", people just know that they aren't supposed to enter `1003` but `jsmith`.

**Display name** (also called the **real user name**) informs us that this is a name of some software object (such as a user account) used for referring to it in user interfaces and program output such as diagnostic or debug messages. The implication is that a display name is not necessarily unique among such objects and cannot be used as a key to unambiguously refer to an object. It is literally for display purposes only. A "display name" is not necessarily a user name; that has to be established by the context. Anything that can have a name can potentially have a display name.

In traditional Unix, the `/etc/passwd` file associates your **numeric user ID** with the **login name** (the textual user ID), and with a **display name**.

## Changing and consequences

The `chfn` utility is used for changing the **display name** aka **real user name** and related information. Doing this should have no consequence.

Changing the **textual user ID** aka **login name** requires privilege; `root` can edit the password file to edit this. The effect will be instant: the new name will appear anywhere in the system where **numeric user IDs** are displayed as their text equivalent. For instance, if someone lists a directory using `ls -l` and that directory contains files owned by that user, they will immediately see the new name, since the `ls` program picks it out of the password database.

The change will break or potentially break various things in the system, and so is a bad idea:

- Firstly, if the new name clashes with another one, that's obviously very bad; I'm mentioning that for the sake of completeness. Let's assume that it's not the case.
- Let's also assume that it's not the case that some user's name is changed without their knowledge, leaving them unable to log in.
- The remaining problem is that in the file system there are likely configuration files which encode the **textual user ID**: both in their path names, and in their contents. These, of course, continue to refer to the old user ID which no longer exists in the password file. The name change is not complete unless all of these are hunted down and repaired.
- The problem can be further compounded if a new password file entry is created which matches the old name. Those configurations now refer to a valid user, but the wrong one.

As an example

1. let's consider that the `sudo` utility exists in the system and is configured via the `/etc/sudoers` file. Suppose the `/etc/sudoers` file grants user `bob` the privilege to run some dangerous administrative command with superuser credentials.
2. Now suppose we rename `bob` to `robert` in the password file and don't update this entry. Now `robert` is not able to run that command any more; the `sudoers` file grants the privilege to `bob` not to `robert`.
3. Next day, a new user is added and happens to be called `bob`. This `bob` now has the privilege to run that administrative command as root.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the difference between user name, display name and log-in name?

- **username** is the account that you typically login to Unix/Linux with.
- **display name** is how the user would display in the GUI, usually first name last name.
- **log-in name** is the same thing as username.

You can see a visual of display name in Ubuntu in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360284/how-do-i-change-my-display-name-on-login).